# Resources for setting up Flex projects with Hudson

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, hudson, flex-lexer

I'm looking into setting up a CI environment for our flex projects. I have very little experience in setting up an environment like this, but have read a lot about it and think we could benefit a lot from this in our projects. I do have experience with ANT and we're currently using it for our building. I've been looking at Hudson for a while and it looks really nice and simple while still having the power to support a proper CI environment.

So basically, my question is if anyone has experience in setting up Flex projects with Hudson? If so, please do share some info on issues, cost/benefit as well what kind of effort is required per project to get up and running with Hudson. I've googled for a while and can proudly say that I know more about both the Fast lexical analyzer and the Hudson River, but little more about the topic of this post =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about anything that can be executed from a command line can be executed via hudson. If your flex app can be built via ant from the command line; it will work just fine in hudson.

This might be helpful:

http://www.subotnik.com/blog/?p=100